# Lemon tree questions

Tags: lemons

What can I do to keep my lemons from yellowing and dropping while still very small.
Also, I'd love some advice about pruning and fertilizing.
Thanks so much.
Janice

Comment: Hi Janice, please add a photo or two of the lemon trees.  Fruit drop can be caused by many things

Comment: And information about approximately where you are.

Comment: I live in the center of San Francisco.

Comment: Will add photos tomorrow.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: How DO I add photos??

Comment: @Janice, When you click 'edit' on your original question, you can add a photo by clicking on the image icon in the header of the 'body' section.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Sorry it's taken me so long.  Husband had major surgery this past week, and I've been rather busy.